# Send complex swipes to Android with Adb/Python (no sendevent)

Tags: python, android, adb

I'm trying to automate some applications on my android phone and I need to swipe from point A (140, 950) to point B (140, 1200) and then to point C (400, 1200) without releasing.

And I already tried input swipe

`adb shell  "input touchscreen swipe 126 459 413 472 & input touchscreen swipe 413 472 407 769"`
but this results in 2 swipes being executed at the same time, not continuously.

Sendevent requires root access

[Appium](https://appium.io/), [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium) and [Monkeyrunner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner) aren't a solution since I'm not testing my own app instead I want to automate existing applications.

There is probably a non-root solution with adb since [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) manages to send such inputs, but I wasn't able to understand the source code

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) `swipe` in [openapi.yaml](https://mrin9.github.io/OpenAPI-Viewer/#/load/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fdtmilano%2FCulebraTester2-public%2Fmaster%2Fopenapi.yaml), it can handle complex swipe patterns and there are also APIs for multitouch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and [CulebraTester-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) to *swipe* like this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from culebratester_client.models import Point

helper = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True).uiAutomatorHelper

# assume google keep is open
helper.ui_device.swipe(segments=[Point(140, 950), Point(140,1200), Point(400, 1200)], segment_steps=100)
```

Using, [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en_US&gl=US) as an example of an app that can draw and the same points from your question we get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution I was looking for!

With `motionevent` from `adb` input you can have more control over the touchscreen.

```
adb shell motionevent <DOWN|UP|MOVE|CANCEL> <x> <y>
```

So with python to move from point A to B and then to C:

```
device.shell(f"motionevent DOWN {aX} {aY}")
device.shell(f"motionevent MOVE {bX} {bY}")
device.shell(f"motionevent UP {cX} {cY}")
```